# ApplicationInsights continuous export

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

In ApplicationInsights Analytics in the query explorer there is a table named traces that contains the telemetry data that is created if you call TrackTrace in c# code. We set up a continuous export to our blob storage but we cannot find the traces data. In the storage account there are just six virtual directories but there are much more tables in the query explorer. Is there any documentation about how the tables are mapped to the directories?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Azure storage container, there should be a folder named Messages, you should be able to see the trace message in the blob file. 
Assuming you have enabled the configuration for Trace in your continuous export.

[image: Continuous export configuration]

In my experience there should be 6 folder if you setup continuous export including Exception, Messages, PerformanceCounter,RDD(remote dependency) ,Request and one for Metrics.

I also browsed for the mapping documentation between App Insight tables and cont export directories but couldn't find any.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Found the folder 'Messages'. Trace was disabled. The folder appeared when cont export is stopped and restarted.

Comment: Yes, it should be restarted to have a update. good to know it  worked.